# Valid signing Identity not found for iphone app with push notifications

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I have created a provisioning profile and done all the certificate stuff. In fact, I have done this several times. So I've done the deleting/revoking everything step. However, no matter what! [image]

I've followed the instructions from here: http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/iphone-configuration-guide/

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: did you check that the bundleIdentifier from the certificate matches with the one in your application? If it does not match it will throw this type of error